# Query to delete sql table row based on attribute in xml file c#

Tags: c#, mysql, xml

I currently have 3 different xml elements to "Add", "Update", and "Delete".  Following these elements, I have a few attributes that will either add, update, or delete from my sql table.  I was able to use  "LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE" query for the "add" and "update" elements, but there is no remove/delete options for the "LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE" query.  The following is my get/set method, Class1 class and my main method class.

Main Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string conString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};"
                + "Server=WWW;Port=XXX;"
                + "Database=inventory;"
                + "uid=YYY;pwd=ZZZ";
            OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(conString);

            {
                XDocument theFile = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\Bob\\Documents\\Update.xml");
                foreach (XElement el in theFile.Root.Elements())
                {
                    if (el.Name == "ADD")
                    {
                       Console.WriteLine("Item {0} ", el.Attribute("invent_id").Value + " was successfully added.");
                        Console.ReadLine();

                        OdbcCommand Command1 = new OdbcCommand("LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Adam/Documents/Update.xml' INTO TABLE item ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<ADD>'", connection);
                        connection.Open();
                        OdbcDataReader reader = Command1.ExecuteReader();
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                    else if (el.Name == "UPDATE")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Item {0} ", el.Attribute("invent_id").Value + " was successfully updated.");
                        Console.ReadLine();

                        OdbcCommand Command2 = new OdbcCommand("LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Adam/Documents/Update.xml' REPLACE INTO TABLE item ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<UPDATE>'", connection);
                        connection.Open();
                        OdbcDataReader reader = Command2.ExecuteReader();
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                    else if (el.Name == "DELETE")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Item {0} ", el.Attribute("invent_id").Value + " was successfully deleted."); ;
                        Console.ReadLine();

                        OdbcCommand Command3 = new OdbcCommand("", connection, connection);
                        connection.Open();
                        OdbcDataReader reader = Command3.ExecuteReader();
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       Console.WriteLine( "Nothing to do");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Class1 Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static object Item_ID { get; set; }
        public static object Invent_id { get; set; }
        public static object Itemsize { get; set; }
        public static object Color { get; set; }
        public static decimal Curr_price { get; set; }
        public static object Qoh { get; set; }
    }
    public class transactions
    {
        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "UPDATE")]
        public class UPDATE
        {
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "qoh")]
            public string Qoh { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "curr_price")]
            public string Curr_price { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "color")]
            public string Color { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "itemsize")]
            public string Itemsize { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "invent_id")]
            public string Invent_id { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "item_id")]
            public string Item_id { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ADD")]
        public class ADD
        {
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "qoh")]
            public string Qoh { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "curr_price")]
            public string Curr_price { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "color")]
            public string Color { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "itemsize")]
            public string Itemsize { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "invent_id")]
            public string Invent_id { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "item_id")]
            public string Item_id { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DELETE")]
        public class DELETE
        {
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "item_id")]
            public string Item_id { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "transactions")]
        public class Transactions
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "UPDATE")]
            public UPDATE UPDATE { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "ADD")]
            public List<ADD> ADD { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "DELETE")]
            public DELETE DELETE { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding my attribute and value to the query like so

```
OdbcCommand Command3 = new OdbcCommand("DELETE FROM item WHERE item_id = " + el.Attribute("item_id").Value, connection);
```

Also, since my queries pull the information straight from my xml file, there is no need for my get and set methods.

Comment: You should parametrize your query to avoid SQL Injection attack.